# Log4j .append=true property fail

Tags: java, log4j

I am using log4j (2.1.16) with a DailyRollingFileAppender, with the append property set to true.
However, everytime I restart the web application it does not append, it simply overwrites the file.

```
log4j.appender.eformsAccess=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.eformsAccess.file=to be set in the code(SchemeActionBean.java)
log4j.appender.eformsAccess.datePattern='.'yyyyMMdd
log4j.appender.eformsAccess.append=true
log4j.appender.eformsAccess.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.eformsAccess.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.eformsAccess.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %m %n
```

So what am I doing wrong?

cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess there are some case-sensitive typos. "File" and "Append" starts with a capital:

```
log4j.appender.eformsAccess.File=someFileNamePlease.log
log4j.appender.eformsAccess.Append=true
```

Comment: Case sensitive indeed.  Once all properties were made upprercase it worked.

Comment: Just to add to this.  I had real problems in development with this.  The file would append great, even on server restart.  But if any code was recompiled it would not append and always create a new file everytime.