# Overwriting log4j not working

Tags: java, properties, configuration, log4j

I have a log4j properties with the following configuration:

```
log4j.appender.LOG=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LOG.File=${directory}/log/app.log
log4j.appender.LOG.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOG.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n
log4j.appender.LOG.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.LOG.append=false
log4j.appender.LOG.bufferedIO=false

log4j.appender.LOGHISTORY=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LOGHISTORY.File=${directory}/log/old-logs/app.log
log4j.appender.LOGHISTORY.File.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.LOGHISTORY.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOGHISTORY.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n
log4j.appender.LOGHISTORY.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.LOGHISTORY.append=true
log4j.appender.LOGHISTORY.bufferedIO=false
```

I want to save a history of previous day's logs in the "log/old-logs" folder. This is working great with the DailyRollingFileAppender.

I also want to have a log of the current day in the "log" folder. This is working fine on my localhost (Windows + Eclipse + Geronimo), but is not working properly on my testing server (Linux + WebSphere). In this case the "app.log" is not being overwritten and everything is being appended at the end of the log.

Comment: in a webapp container log4j.properties might be put in WEB-INF/ in order to be loaded

Comment: The server-log4j.properties is based in the server.

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK `Rolling file appender` will only roll the file when a specified a max size is reached . 
The above scenario might be working for you in the local copy each time application is restarted, the log file will overwritten because of `.append = false` . On a production environment I do not think that the server is restarted that is why the file is written as per `.append = false` . Could this be your case why overwriting did not work ?

Comment: Yes, it could be indeed. So I guess I should use DailyRollingFileAppender, but I don't want to keep the history logs, just the one of the present day.

Comment: You could zip the historic logs using `TimeBasedRollingPolicy`

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468735/log4j-append-true-property-fail).
You should use Append with a capital A.

```
    log4j.appender.LOG.Append=false 
    log4j.appender.LOGHISTORY.Append=true
```

Comment: No, everything is being appended at the end of the log without warnings and errors.

Answer (score 0):

For the RollingFileAppender, you need to specify the property "MaxFileSize". This will tell log4j to roll the file over when it reaches that size.

eg: Below will roll over when log file size reaches  2MB

```
log4j.appender.LOG=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LOG.File=${directory}/log/app.log
log4j.appender.LOG.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOG.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n
log4j.appender.LOG.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.LOG.MaxFileSize=2MB
log4j.appender.LOG.MaxBackupIndex=2 (This is optional, tells log4j the maximum backup files to take)
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not want to roll the file over when it reaches a size, I want to roll it over everyday. The problem is that the configuration on top is working on windows+geronimo environment, but not on linux+websphere.